# php's file_exists is returning false for file name having foreign language characters

Tags: php, file-exists

```
$file_name = "x:/htdocs/host/sales_documents/testvilkår, webhotell og domenenavn_2ccda.pdf";

if(!file_exists($file_name))
{   
    echo "<h2>404 Error</h2>";
    exit;
}
```

File name is a valid file and also it really exist, but still `file_exists` is returning `false`.
Can you tell me what is a reason behind it?

Comment: Unix or Windows? Tried backslashes?

Comment: try enclosing filename with {}

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm having a similair problem having a "," and a space next to each other that's bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

check your file path. your code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change slashes to constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and add `file://` to path.